# pands doesn't recognize missing values in CSV

Tags: pandas, csv

In the CSV there's missing values in many columns but
the code shows there's no missing values.
how can i fix this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As can be seen in the [`pandas` documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), the values that are used in your csv to indicate missing values (i.e. `"None"`) is not in the default list of values used to mark missing values:

> Additional strings to recognize as NA/NaN. If dict passed, specific
> per-column NA. By default the following values are interpreted as NaN:
> ‘’, ‘#N/A’, ‘#N/A N/A’, ‘#NA’, ‘-1.#IND’, ‘-1.#QNAN’, ‘-NaN’, ‘-nan’,
> ‘1.#IND’, ‘1.#QNAN’, ‘’, ‘N/A’, ‘NA’, ‘NULL’, ‘NaN’, ‘n/a’, ‘nan’,
> ‘null’.

Simply providing the value used in your file for the `na_values` argument should solve the issue:

```
pandas.read_csv("file.csv", na_values="None")
```

Comment: thanks but 
i changed "None" to "NULL" in CSV
and also tried to add the line 
na_values="None"

and both didn't work......... (still output shows same)

Comment: Then it's likely because the file is not being read correctly, as it seems that it recognizes three columns whereas your file has many more. Make sure you are specifying the correct delimiter used in your file for the `sep` argument.

Comment: thanks
kidney_df=pd.read_csv(r"C:\...\xx.csv", "rb",  sep="") 
is this right way? i tried to do that with sep but doesn't work with this error

TypeError: read_csv() got multiple values for argument 'sep'

Comment: You don't need to use the `"rb"` value, using just `pandas.read_csv("filename.csv", sep=",", na_values="None")` should do the trick.

Comment: Great Thanks! Works! How did you know all this stuff?

Comment: By just reading the documentation of the function and the meaning of the different arguments.

Comment: Thank you very much!